# Convenient way to upload a file to a server's application directory?

Tags: files, permissions, root, scp, application

I very often need to upload some kind of file to a server, to put some application directory somewhere. Since my user account is of course unprivileged, I generally have to do this:

```
scp file.txt myserver:
ssh myserver
$ sudo cp file.txt /etc/app/config
$ sudo chown app:app /etc/app/config/file.txt
```

Four steps.

I didn't go through sysadmin school, so I'm just wondering if I missed something. Is there a better way? What do other people do?

- Write local scripts for this kind of task?
- Add your user account to the same group as every application, and hope that group perms are enough?
- Log in as root?
- Make app accounts login-able?

Comment: There are several methods outlined in this SU Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/138893/scp-to-remote-server-with-sudo

Comment: Thanks. Most of those lead to the above. One useful thing is the rsync-path option, leading to a command like `rsync --rsync-path="sudo -u appowner rsync" -e ssh file.txt myserver:/etc/app/config`.

Answer (score 0):

with proper key settongs, assuming you can set thoses keys in myserver's app home dir.

```
scp file.txt app@myserver:/etc/app/config/file.txt
```

Step 1)

in local host, check in $HOME/.ssh for any file name `id_rsa.pub`, if found goto step 3.

Step 2)

If not found, in local host (starting host)

```
cd $HOME
mkdir .ssh
chmod go-rwx .ssh
cd .ssh
ssh-keygen
```

accept all defaults, do not put a password on key.

Step 3) 
log on myserver with app account (or sudo to it).
repeat .ssh creation if needed.

copy `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys` if latter do not exists.
If it exists, just concat `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`

This should do the trick

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding, but I think you're just trying to solve the problem of connecting to a server without a password, which I already have set up. The messy bit is copying a file to the hypothetical /etc/app/config directory which my unprivileged user doesn't have write access to. (And repeating that for every other app dir....)

Comment: well, in that case, copying your public key in remote  hosts using sudo didn't do it.